# XmlHttpRequest status 0 on google NEW sheets format

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api, google-apps

I am trying to get data from a NEW google sheet (the new version of sheets). For that i have the following javascript code:

```
function loadData() {
          //OLD google sheets
          //var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv";
          //NEW google sheets
          var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12UpSf3_AsuThoNc-oZacDqnY0gQpNCGa3nsTEr03lFk/export?format=csv&gid=0";
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                  //document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
                  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                  //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
              }
          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET", url,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
      }
```

and the HTML for that is:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadData(); return false">Load Spreadsheet Data</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

The problem is i can't get anything from the new format google sheets and with the old format works fine. I always get status=0, you can see this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2r9bB/)

The sheet is published to the web and is shared to anyone who has the link.

Please help

Answer (score -2):

My Working Code
For More Help: 923405588490

```
<Script="Text/Javascript"></Script>
<Script>



    function loadData() {

  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=1HrS3DKA8LPCl3UFK6zrdmZprhK2rWNFj0EjDSkyu6b4&single=true&gid=0&range=A2&output=csv";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);


setTimeout(myTimeout1, 5000)

function myTimeout1() {
var data=document.getElementById("display").innerHTML
   alert(data);

//var a='fsddsdabc';

//document.getElementById('id1').value=data ; 

alert("Success")


}



}
</Script>
<html>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadData()">Load Spreadsheet Data</button>
    <div id="display"></div>
<input type="Text" id="id1" </input>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers rarely provide much insight, please try to explain what you have changed and how your code is working, both for OP and for future visitors.